# Remove a directory permanently from git

Tags: git

In my personal git repo, I have a directory that contains thousands of small images that are no longer needed. Is there a way to delete them from the entire git history? I have tried

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch imgs" HEAD
```

and

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -fr imgs' HEAD
```

but the size of the git repo remains unchanged. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure, but have you tried running `git gc` after? Maybe they're still there as garbage...

Comment: You'll have to remove all old references (e.g. branch names, tags), and you can run `git gc --aggressive` afterwards.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually none of these techniques workedfor me. 
I found the most reliable was was to simply pull locally into another repo:

```
git pull file://$(pwd)/myGitRepo
```

It also saves you the hassle of deletig old tags.

see the story on my blog:
http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2009/07/10/git-script-to-show-largest-pack-objects-and-trim-your-waist-line/

Comment: This seems to be the deal close for me. I have documented the Windows specific steps here: http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/?p=80

Comment: The question was "Is there a way to delete them (files in directory) from the entire git history?" How does this answer help do that?

Comment: @hitautodestruct because the question correctly shows how to remove the object from the active tree, but is missing the how to remove the _dangling_ references to those files. 
Thanks for the blast from the past - zombie answer from ten years ago =D

Comment: I know it's an oldy, but I have no idea how this answers the question. The question asks how to modify an existing git repo to remove a folder, and this just shows how to pull into a different repo - this clearly does not directly answer the question

Answer (score 33):

The ProGit book has an interesting section on [Removing Object](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery).

It does end with this:

> Your history no longer contains a reference to that file.
>   However, your `reflog` and a new set of refs that Git added when you did the `filter-branch` under `.git/refs/original` still do, so you have to remove them and then repack the database. You need to get rid of anything that has a pointer to those old commits before you repack:

```
$ rm -Rf .git/refs/original
$ rm -Rf .git/logs/
$ git gc
$ git prune --expire
```

(`git prune --expire` is not mandatory but can remove the directory content from the loose objects)
Backup everything before doing those commands, just in case ;)

Answer (score 13):

git-filter-branch by default saves old refs in `refs/original/*` namespace.

You need to delete them, and **then** do `git gc --prune=now`

Answer (score 10):

*Brandon Thomson* asked in a comment to *Rainer Blome*'s solution if this just fixed the gitk view or if the refs will be really gone.  A good way to check this is to remember one of the sha1 hashes (or a unique prefix of it) of the old commits and try

```
$ git ls-tree hash-value
```

This should show you the content of the repos main folder as it was in this commit. After

```
$ rm -Rf .git/refs/original
$ rm -Rf .git/logs/
```

as shown by *VonC* and removing the `refs/original/…` lines from `.git/info/refs` and `.git/packed-refs` as shown by *Rainer Blome*, a final

```
$ git gc --prune=now
```

made not only the refs, but also the old objects (commits, trees, and blobs) go away.  The above shown `git ls-tree hash-value` proves this.
Another nice command to check this is `git count-objects -v` (run it before the filter-brach and after the pruning and compare the size).

**Note:** As I'm not allowed yet to comment on the other answers, I had to write a new one although it mainly combines previous given answers.

Comment: This answer *seems* like the correct solution to me.  However, I don't understand why the total size of my repository is unchanged.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to go the manual cleanup route, there are some more files that may also contain
a ref to the position of your original branch before the git-filter-branch.
For example, I filtered my "home" branch:

.git/info/refs:

> 179ad3e725816234a7182476825862e28752746d refs/original/refs/heads/home

.git/packed-refs:

> 179ad3e725816234a7182476825862e28752746d refs/original/refs/heads/home

After I removed those lines, gitk did not show the old commits any more.

Comment: worked for me, although I kindof wonder if this just fixed the gitk view or if the refs will actually be gc'd now

Answer (score 2):

As this is an old question, perhaps some of this wasn't possible back then. This also assumes you're using bash or cygwin.

**Warning:** The second and third lines will permanently delete all commits unreachable from your branches/tags.

After running `filter-branch`, do

```
for ref in $(git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' refs/original); do git update-ref -d $ref; done
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
```

`git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)'` gets the reference names, and `git update-ref -d` deletes the reference. It is generally better not to modify the `.git` folder directly, and in particular this command handles the case when the refs are in `packed-refs`.

The second and third lines are taken directly from [How to clean up unused side-branches in your commit trees?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756250/how-to-clean-up-unused-side-branches-in-your-commit-trees).

Answer (score 2):

**Answer for the year 2021**

This surprisingly turns out to be hard task. Google turns up pages that are way back dated to 2009 and StackOverflow discussions almost a decade old. Lot of those things don't work any more!

Here's what works (also recommended way according to git docs):

First install `git-filter-repo`:

```
pip install git-filter-repo
```

Next, delete folders from git history. This will rewrite entire Git history except for the excluded folder!

```
git filter-repo --force --invert-paths --path to/folder1 --path to/folder
```

Next, add back the remotes:

```
git remote add origin https://...
```

Next, force push upstream:

```
git push --force --set-upstream origin master
```

So that's the bunch of commands but I haven't found a shorter better way.