# Git history cleanup doesn't seem to have an effect

Tags: xcode, git

i ran the following 2 commands to clean up .pbxuser and .mode1v3 files from my git repository, but afterwards when i e.g. fire up **gitx** i can still see them in the history.

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch *.pbxuser" HEAD
rm -rf .git/refs/original/ && git reflog expire --all && git gc --aggressive --prune
```

What did i misunderstand here? The commands seem to do the job but why is **gitx** still viewing the diffs in its history?

Regards, Erik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clone your cleaned repository, and see if gitx still view the diff in that (cloned repo) history.
(see "[Remove a directory permanently from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git/1225302#1225302)")

Comment: Thank's, I'll try that. Sorry for the double post didn't find this question earlier.

Comment: Seems that my filter command was just wrong somehow. The command from your linked question did the job. Thanks!

Comment: @eaigner so you didn't need to clone the repo? only to filter-branch and gc prune?