# How to use my changes for merge in git?

Tags: git, msysgit

How do I force "my changes" when merging in git? Someone put all bin directories in git and now I have a terrible merge conflict :(

Now it says the following:

> When you have resolved this problem
>   run "git rebase --continue". If you
>   would prefer to skip this patch,
>   instead run "git rebase --skip". To
>   restore the original branch and stop
>   rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

I do NOT want to merge, i just want to delete all those files using my changes.

**EDIT:** Most of the files was successfully merged, either through automatic merge or because there was no conflict. However quite a few still exist like the following one.

> warning: Cannot merge binary files:
>   src/reports/obj/Debug/TempPE/GroupMailDS.Designer.cs.dll
>   (HEAD vs. added gitignore)

Comment: Perhaps you need to provide more detail on the conflicts, but can't you just do `git rm` on the files that you don't want; fixup any remaining real conflicts and `git rebase --continue`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not 100% confident about this, but I think this is a good case for this:

```
git merge otherbranch -s recursive -X ours
```

That command attempts to merge the topic branch into your checked out branch using the recursive strategy. The -X ours option is a subset of the recursive strategy that automatically resolves conflicts by making the assumption that your currently checked out branch is authoritative.

Comment: I have to try this because if that works that's greatness beyond the power of the darkside for anyone responsible of jedi/master!

Comment: Wow! That's exactly what I was looking for. Talk about ludicrous speed! :) I believe it's a perfect situation to use this. All I wanted was to overwrite the other branch with my changes in case of conflicts even if it wasn't exactly what I asked for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- `git rm` the `obj`  directory (which contains all those binary files and shouldn't have been committed in the first place)
- add a .gitignore directive to make sure any future obj directory won't appear in the `git status` (and won't be added)
- `git push` that new tree, helping to propagate the fact that '`obj`' directory should disappear from other Git repos as well (hence triggering no merge at all).

If you can have the consent of all the other participants, you could:

- [remove permanently that directory from your Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git)
- `git push -f` (forced push) to a "central" git repo from which the other developers could fetch and reset their own branches.

But since it involves replacing published history by a new one, it should be done only if the other users agree.

Comment: It makes sense. I never thought of deleting the directory:)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can just replace their binaries with yours (since no merge is really possible) or just git rm the unwanted binaries. After you have done, just git rebase --continue

Comment: Or even better, like VonC suggested to git rm the directory