# automatically removing conflict markers

Tags: git

What is a quick way to remove conflict markers from source code?

I have just merged some changes, and now I have a lot of files in conflict.

I started to manually remove them. However, this would take too much of my time.

Is there a way git can automate this?

I just want to keep all HEAD's and discard all the rest.

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
.
.
.
.
=======
.
.
.
.
>>>>>>> ffa5c899d36e779c23cff8b33f48f2ab95ef08c8
```

Comment: Your question isn't really how to automatically remove the markers - that's a scary thought, since there's no guarantee that what's left will make any sense. You're asking how to keep a particular version in a merge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look this: [keep either file in merge conflicts](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/25/keep-either-file-in-merge-conflicts.html)

Answer (score 5):

This post will be useful to you: [How to use my changes for merge in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3100167/how-to-use-my-changes-for-merge-in-git/3103163#3103163)

I think what you want is: `git merge otherbranch -s recursive -X ours`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to resolve the conflicts by hand, instead of `git mergetool`.

There are many merge tools described on StackOverflow, like:

- [Meld](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/meld)
- [p4merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/p4merge)

Resolving conflicts is a pretty wide topic.

Some common practices:

- checkout local version (restore changes)

  `git reset -- filename`
- checkout remote version (override changes)

  `git checkout ORIG_HEAD -- filename`

See also:

- [Git on Windows: How do you set up a mergetool? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426026/git-on-windows-how-do-you-set-up-a-mergetool)
- [What's the best visual merge tool for Git? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137102/whats-the-best-visual-merge-tool-for-git)