# How can I completely remove a file from a git repository?

Tags: git

I noticed recently that the project files my text editors use (along with some other junk) got added the git repository for the project.  Since they aren't actually part of the project, I'd like to remove them, but `git rm` doesnt remove the old versions from the repository, and I couldnt find anything else that looks promising.

Comment: partial duplicate, definitely covered by previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/git-remove-file-accidentally-added-to-the-repository http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git

Answer (score 146, accepted):

The tool you want is `git filter-branch`. Its usage is described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), but basically:

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f my_file' HEAD
```

will remove "my_file" from *every* commit.

Notice that this rewrites every commit, so if you push into a remote repository, you have to (a) force the update, and (b) everyone else who pulled from you will now have duplicate commits (since you rewrote the history), as described on the [`git rebase` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase).

Comment: I recommend to add `--prune-empty` so any empty commits generated as a result will be removed too.

Comment: How does this work on a repository with many files with the same name in different directories ? Does it delete all files with the same name ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey: In that case, you'd use a longer, unique path.

Comment: later should I do `git push --force` ? @mipadi

Comment: @mipadi, what if I deleted these files locally, long ago? (and committed and pushed these deletions)  How can I delete the files from the repository in this case?

Comment: Everyone should remember that this WILL DELETE the files from your current working directory as well. This has been obvious to me every time I've used this command, except for this time.

Comment: @alper `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`

Comment: Can I apply this for file patterns like: file names that are `*.save` ?

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I get:     + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (WARNING: Ref 'r...p' is unchanged:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: WARNING: this can be very long operation !
I don t understand that the first time i have runned that command ...

Comment: I had to add "if" into a filter command: ```git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -e DIR ];then rm -rf DIR ; fi' HEAD```; without "if" it reported "Permission denied"

Comment: actually not sure about adding "if" so take my advice with a grain of salt (this is because I sometimes get "Permission denied" even with the "if", not sure why)

Answer (score 11):

This is what `git filter-branch` is for, but beware that your repo history will change, and the commit hashes will be different after history rewrite.

If you also want to free the space, I recommend that you use `git forget-blob`, because `git filter-branch` alone will not make git forget your file, as it may still be referenced by remotes, reflog, tags and such.

`git forget-blob main.c.swp`

You can get more information [here](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/01/18/completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository-with-git-forget-blob/)

Answer (score 5):

It's now recommended to use [git-filter-repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) instead. Running `git-filter-branch` actually prints:

```
WARNING: git-filter-branch has a glut of gotchas generating mangled history
```