# Completely remove a file from whole git repository

Tags: git, github, git-commit

Using git for a project, I accidentally added to a commit a big `.zip` file. I didn't notice until I started uploading it to github. When I noticed, I hit `ctrl-c`, `git remove`, `git commit` and uploaded it again (now with the file untracked).

I know that this wasn't the right choice to do, because once I committed the `.zip`, it stays in the repo until I revert the commit, but sadly I didn't.

Now, when someone tries to download from the repo, it takes a lot of time to do it, sometimes yields `git the remote end hung up unexpectedly` (which I've read can be solved by doing some `git config`) and is very annoying.

My point is: **is there a way to tell further pull/fetch request that forget this specific file in this specific commit version?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Completely remove file from all Git repository commit history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-file-from-all-git-repository-commit-history)

Comment: @Cupcake Thanks for the heads up :) You can see it was even part of the answer. The questions are not identical per se, not to mention that IMHO, __this answer is a lot  better__, with better documentation and useful links than all provided in that duplicate. Also, your help would've been very helpful _1 year ago_ ;)

Comment: related https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Github provide a [useful help page on removing files](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) like this. There are also other questions on StackOverflow which cover this

- [Completely remove unwanted file from Git repository history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307828/completely-remove-unwanted-file-from-git-repository-history)
- [How can I completely remove a file from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository?lq=1)

See also [this section of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History#_the_nuclear_option_filter_branch), an example given there:

> To remove a file named passwords.txt from your entire history, you can
>   use the --tree-filter option to filter-branch:
>
> ```
> $ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f passwords.txt' HEAD
> Rewrite 6b9b3cf04e7c5686a9cb838c3f36a8cb6a0fc2bd (21/21)
> Ref 'refs/heads/master' was rewritten
> ```

After the cleanup, you could also try a [git gc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) to further compress and clean up for repository.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `git gc`. My dot git directory just shrank from 35M to 20M.

Comment: after this how could I commit? @Paul Dixon

Comment: FWIW, that first link (to the GitHub page) seems like the best to me by a longshot (it uses the significantly faster `--index-filter`; its command affects all branches and tags (like the question asks); it provides relevant warnings; and it describes very useful pre- and post-deletion steps).

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool now called "BFG Repo-Cleaner", it's mentioned on github.com as an alternative to filter-branch https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Link to the tool's page https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/