# git push origin master doesn't register changes to repo

Tags: git, web

So I'm trying to publish my personal website using Github Pages. It originally had a couple of video files, but Mr.Terminal told me git doesn't allow files of that size and I conceded. I removed the files, "git add"-ed the folder, and committed the changes. When I type in "git push origin master", however, it still gives me the same error. Am I approaching this wrong?

[image]

Comment: It looks like you didn't remove the large video files from the commit. ('Ticks and Leeches.mp4', 'Awake And Alive.mp4'). Even using `git rm <FILENAME>` to remove the large files won't help you, because these would still be pushed as history. Follow the directions here to purge: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Completely remove a file from whole git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877530/completely-remove-a-file-from-whole-git-repository)

Comment: I'll try that thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't have an important history of changes, it will be simpler to create a new local repository with your files.

The problem is with a history of git repository - if you once added a binary file to the git repository, it will be saved in the history forever (and will take a space too). You can delete the file by command `git rm my-binary-file` and it will be delete the file from "current" version. But it will be appear in the history anyway.

In other case (when you don't want to loose a history of your changes) - read @Ray's answer

Comment: Aye I did the whole new repo thing its working fine now :D

Answer (score 2):

Git isn't intended to store large binary files--it's source control.  Github is a Git repo (as well as a number of productivity tools) and it's core functionality is tied to supporting Git repo functionality.

The screenshot in your post clearly shows you're trying to add 2 files that exceed the hard 100MB limit Github imposes.

You also have one file over the 'recommended' limit of 50MB.

Here's the answer:

- Remove the 3 large files from being tracked in your local repo
- Assuming you just added them in the latest commit before your attempted push you need to scrub them from your repo like this: https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/
- If you've done a number of commits and this isn't from your last commit, do as one one of the commenter's suggest or this: [Completely remove a file from whole git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16877530/completely-remove-a-file-from-whole-git-repository)
- Try the push again

Comment: I'll try and revert

Comment: Thanks anyway though!

Comment: I ended up redoing the whole thing from scratch..all in good shape now