# Git merge branch with its modified clone which has no history

Tags: git, github, merge

I created a new branch called *new* based on *develop* (clone). At the beginning I messed up by accidentally committing 100MB+ file. A few days later, I tried to push to remote and it failed because of this big file. I haven't found another way to remove this file than to remove all history (now the branch *new* has only one commit). How can I merge this branch with *develop* so *new* contains all history from *develop* ?

I've cloned the repo with:

```
git clone http://...
```

And then

```
git checkout -b new develop
```

Current *new* state:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
...
```

I *could* make another branch from develop, overwrite it with *new* files, commit and merge back to *develop*, but that would make all my deleted files stay.

Comment: See. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository

Comment: I don't have a copy which still contains the history.

Comment: @Dalius please add more details about how you created `new` the first time, and how you got it to its current state now.  Please add the commands used. Is it possible to add a `git log` to your question? Also, [How can I completely remove a file from a git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository) could still apply if the commit is still recorded in your reflog and your repo hasn't garbage collected dangling commits yet.