# How to remove sensitive data from a file in github history

Tags: git, github, revert

I am using a shared github repository to collaborate on a project. Because i am an idiot, I committed and pushed a script file containing a password which I don't want to share (Yes, i can change the password, but I would like to remove it anyway!).

Is there any way to revert the commits from github's history, remove the password locally and then recommit and push the updated files? I do not want to remove the file completely, and I would rather not lose the commit history on github.

(This question
[How can I completely remove a file from a git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458685/how-can-i-completely-remove-a-file-from-a-git-repository)
shows how to remove a sensitive file, but not how to edit sensitive data from a file, so this is not a duplicate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to substitute text from files in git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4110652/how-to-substitute-text-from-files-in-git-history)

Comment: *I would rather not lose the commit history on github*: To be clear, you still want the commit history to contain the viewable revision of the file with the password?

Comment: No - sorry i was uncleae - i want the rest of the commit history but with teh password removed

Answer (score 20):

I would recommend to use the new [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo), which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).

---

First: do that one copy of your local repo (a new clone)

See "[Content base filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#_content_based_filtering)":

At the end, you can (if you are the only one working on that repository) do a `git push --force`

> If you want to modify file contents, you can do so based on a list of expressions in a file, one per line.
> For example, with a file named `expressions.txt` containing:
>
> ```
> p455w0rd
> foo==>bar
> glob:*666*==>
> regex:\bdriver\b==>pilot
> literal:MM/DD/YYYY==>YYYY-MM-DD
> regex:([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{4})==>\3-\1-\2
> ```
>
> then running
>
> ```
> git filter-repo --replace-text expressions.txt
> # on Windows
> git-filter-repo --replace-text expressions.txt
>   ^^^
> ```
>
> will go through and **replace**:
>
> - `p455w0rd` with `***REMOVED***`,
> - `foo` with `bar`,
> - any line containing `666` with a blank line,
> - the word `driver` with `pilot` (but not if it has letters before or after; e.g. drivers will be unmodified),
> - the exact text `MM/DD/YYYY` with `YYYY-MM-DD` and
> - date strings of the form `MM/DD/YYYY` with ones of the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

[gaborous](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1121352/gaborous) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850631/how-to-remove-sensitive-data-from-a-file-in-github-history/59853332#comment129640350_59853332):

> On Windows, `git-filter-repo` works as a separate Python module (that you can install as such using `pip install`), so you need to add a dash in the above command for it to work on Windows:
>
> ```
> git-filter-repo --replace-text expressions.txt
> ```

Comment: Note to self: That was my **23000th answer** on Stack Overflow (in 136 months), 5 months after the [22000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57387243/6309). Before that: [21000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856158/6309), [20000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915541/6309), [19000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49421565/6309), [18000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46860745/6309), [17000th answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43703956/6309), [16000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40698777/6309), [15000th answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37539529/6309) ...

Comment: Works like a charm! On Windows, `git-filter-repo` works as a separate Python module (that you can install as such using `pip install`), so you need to add a dash in the above command for it to work on Windows: `git-filter-repo --replace-text expressions.txt`

Comment: @gaborous Thank you for the feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I appreciate your follow-up on this old question, thank you :-) Yes feel free to add my comment in your answer! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If your content had already been pushed to GitHub, after scrubbing the repository with `git filter-repo` or `bfg` and force-pushing the cleaned up repository, [reach out to GitHub Support](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository#fully-removing-the-data-from-github). They will then make sure all references to the commit and it's files are deleted from issue references, pull requests and the cached data GitHub keeps. Only then the password will really be gone from *your* repositories.

If anyone forked your repository and synced in the sensitive commit, then there is no way to force GitHub to clean up their repositories too. You'll need to ask each owner of the forks to go through the same process.

**Consider your password burned**. Since your password is out there and since it will take some time to be fully removed, there is ample time for a bad actor to scrape your current repo state and store the password for later use. **Always reset the password**. Do not fall for the trap of thinking you may still be safe.

Make sure any other contributors on your project clone a fresh copy or rebase there local changes on the fixed repository. **Removing data from history will cause the commit-ids of all subsequent commits to change.**

Answer (score 0):

Use BFG : https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

To remove files:

```
$ bfg --delete-files <file to remove>  my-repo.git
```

[image]

---

You can also use this tool to remove passwords and ant sensitive data as well.

Prepare a replacement file with the content you wish to replace and use BFG to clean it out.

```
bfg --replace-text passwords.txt  my-repo.git
```

---

```
# Example of the passwords.txt file: 
string1                   # Replace string ***REMOVED***' (default text)
string2==>replacementText # replace with 'replacementText' instead
string3=>                 # replace with the empty string
```

Comment: Hmmm.. this will clean my git repo, but if I then push to github, won't it just add another (clean)  commit and leave the password in teh github history?

Comment: Using BFG will remove it from the **entire** history but you will have to force push to overwrite current content

Comment: Have installed bfg but `bfg --replace-text passwords.txt` gives me a syntax error

    `bfg --replace-text passwords.txt
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `SyntaxError` looks like Python error. I suspect you ran the command in a Python command line. Run it in an OS console, OS command interpreter.

Comment: `git-filter-repo` provides a replacement based on their tool but mimicking BFG's syntax, but with some fixed bugs, called [bfg-ish](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/bfg-ish).