# Remove cognito credentials from commit in the git history, Rewrite commit in master with password to remove

Tags: git, git-rewrite-history

The commit has Cognito Pool ID, Cognito App Client ID. I want to remove just this cognito credentials from the commit in the git history. I don't want to remove that commit and after this commit there are 500 more commits in master. i would like to resolve without getting merge conflicts. because when i tried to edit using git rebase interactive it was giving merge conflicts. so please provide any solution to fix it or any tools which fix this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove sensitive data from a file in github history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59850631/how-to-remove-sensitive-data-from-a-file-in-github-history)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+sensitive+data+from+commit