# Remove old folder from a public git repo

Tags: git, github

I have a fork in Github of a repo that has large binary files in the vendor folder. I want to remove that folder, so that the repo returns to a normal size.

Problems/Challenges:

- **There are 7 – non sequential – commits** concerning the vendor folder.
- **There are hundreds of commits separating those commits**. Since they are OSS contributions, it would not be appropriate to lose that history.
- It is **OK** if people who has forked my repo cannot use this new one. None of them has new commits. They can fork again without problems.

I would like to hear suggestions on how to proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to want to look at [`git filter-branch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-filter-branch), and more specifically, the `--tree-filter` option for it. For example:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -r vendor/*" HEAD
```

Comment: I would like to add that things aren't "deleted officially" in git for 90 days. If you want your repo to shrink, you need to set the expiry date for garbage collection to immediate, garbage collect and then set the expiry for 90 days again.

Comment: Either `git gc --prune=now` (clearing the reflogs first if they are on), or just re-clone the repo and use the new clone (which will automatically be a new minimal repo, since unused stuff isn't cloned).

Comment: I tried this in my local repo and it worked. But when I do git status I see that "Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 181 and 181 different commit(s) each, respectively."

Comment: So I can rewrite the history of my local repo, but is there any way to push those changes to github?

Comment: ...besides creating a new repo.

Comment: You can `git push origin HEAD --force` to force GitHub to take the new version instead of the existing.

Comment: @amber: And once I push those changes, will the public repo garbage collect all the unused blobs? That is, the online repo will be of the same size as my local repo?

Comment: That depends on how GitHub handles it. I believe they gc their repositories pretty aggressively.