# Remove contents of a commit from a git repo after its already been git -rm'ed and pushed

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

So we had a user add and then remove a large directory of files in her workspace it two distinct commits.  She then pushed her changes to the central repo and to the end user it looks like a noop.  The problem is our central repo has jumped by 50x in size because of this.  I have tried several things with filter branch and its just not working.

So the folder that was added was at the root level.  The name of it was .core

I have tried the following filter-branch based on links:

http://www.somethingorothersoft.com/2009/09/08/the-definitive-step-by-step-guide-on-how-to-delete-a-directory-permanently-from-git-on-widnows-for-dumbasses-like-myself/

http://dound.com/2009/04/git-forever-remove-files-or-folders-from-history/

[Remove a directory permanently from git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216733/remove-a-directory-permanently-from-git)

The final commands I have tried looks like this:

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch .core" --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
rm -Rf .git/refs/original
rm -Rf .git/refs/logs
git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The resulting output says the Ref is unchanged.  I have tried changing the reference of .core to various variations such as ./.core, *.core/*, ..... with nothing getting removed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [the BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative to `git-filter-branch`, specifically designed for removing unwanted files from Git history.

Carefully follow the BFG's [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) - the core part is just this:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar  --delete-folders .core  my-repo.git
```

Any folder named `.core` (that isn't in your *latest* commit) will be removed from your Git repository's history. You can then use `git gc` to clean away the dead data:

```
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

The BFG is typically at least [10-720x](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsR1d5Zpes8HdER3VGU1a3dOcmVHMmtzT2dsS2xNenc#gid=0) faster than running `git-filter-branch`, and generally easier to use.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: Out of curiosity: Would this tool be rewriting history?  If I were to checkout the commit in question, how would Git deliver the large files to me?

Comment: Ok, we use BFG to do cleaning up of big blobs, never tried it on a folder.  I can confirm this works extremely well.  Just as a note, there was an error on output using bfg-1.12.3:

        /gitstore/repositories/test/root.git.bfg-report/2015-04-22/11-02-43
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:900)
        at scalax.io.support.FileUtils$$anonfun$scalax$io$support$FileUtils$$preOpen$1.apply(FileUtils.scala:66)

Comment: Peter, I get the same exception, did you find a solution?